# Выравнивание элементов по высоте vh100

Tags: css, flexbox

Есть такая ситуация, при попытке выравнивать по высоте p 1,2

Элементы находятся не по середине. Как можно решить эту проблему?

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#one {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#two {
  height: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">
  <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
  <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
  <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
    <div id="two">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/04c2wmo6/7/)

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#one {
  background: red;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#two {
  flex: 1 0 0px;
  background: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="one">
    <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
    <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
    <p>qwqweqwewqeweq</p>
    <div id="two">
      <p>1</p>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```